# enable/disable options in PreferenceFragment at runtime

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is, that I have multiple checkboxes in a PreferenceFragment. If user checks a checkbox, I want to enable the other checkboxes. Similarly, when the checkbox is unchecked, the other checkboxes are disable. How can I do this real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dependency in the XML for the other checkboxes and reference the first checkbox in it.
That way they will automatically be disabled/enabled depending on the state of the first one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency